# Class types in Array of Something (PHP)

Tags: php

This is just for easier to track and read the code, I want my php code follow what the Java did.

For example:

```
foreach($objects as  $object){
 do something with $object . 
}
```

I want the $object is clear what kind of object is it ...

I tried 
 foreach($objects as (ClassOfSomething) $object):

but it produced error ...

I want my code easy to read and the object recognized by the IDE directly (I am using Intellij Idea btw)

Comment: PHP doesn't use static typing, it figures out the type dynamically.

Comment: If you want to document the types of variables, use phpDoc.

Comment: Why are you using Intellij Idea for PHP? It's a Java IDE isn't it?

Comment: @vascowhite IntelliJ IDEA is an IDE written in Java but supporting many languages via plugins, including PHP. JetBrains, the company behind IntelliJ produce also PhpStorm, an IDE dedicated to PHP development, but it is basically a selection of plugins that could be manually installed into IntelliJ too.

Comment: Yes, I use PHPStorm. I just thought idea was Java only. I was probably confused by the web site `"The Most Intelligent IDE
for the Java Platform"`. :)

Comment: I use Intelij Idea for my java project but I could use it for php and still have fun with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this phpDoc comment before the loop:

```
/** @var ClassOfSomething $object */
```

This is in standard [phpDoc](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/index.html) format, and most IDEs, including IntelliJ pick this up and use it for autocompletion etc.